# comparing 2 inconsistent xml files using linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have 2 xml files, product.xml and rule.xml.

Rule.xml

```
  <Attr>
      <name>3D</name>
      <category addto="name">AddString</category>
      <transformingvalue>{0} capable</transformingvalue>
      <comparingvalue></comparingvalue>
    </Attr>
 <Attr>
      <name>Diagonal Size</name>
      <name>Diagonal Size (cm)</name>
      <name>Display Size</name>
      <name>Display Type</name>
      <name>Tablet size</name>
      <name>Tablet size (cm)</name>
      <category addto="transformed">AddString</category>
      <transformingvalue>{0} Display</transformingvalue>
      <comparingvalue></comparingvalue>
    </Attr>
 <Attr>
      <name>Battery Life</name>
      <category sub="ToValueBasedOnValueAddStringToTransformed">StringToNumAddString</category>
      <transformingvalue id="1">{0} hours</transformingvalue>
      <transformingvalue id="2">{0} mins</transformingvalue>
      <tranformingvalue id="3" >Battery Life-{0}</tranformingvalue>
      <comparingvalue operator="&lt;=">60</comparingvalue>
    </Attr>
```

Product.xml

```
<Attr>
  <name>3D</name>
  <value>yes</value>
</Attr>
<Attr>
  <name>Diagonal Size</name>
  <value>20.1in</value>
</Attr>
<Attr>
  <name>Display Size</name>
  <value>11.1in</value>
</Attr>
<Attr>
  <name>Battery Life</name>
  <value>5</value>
</Attr>
```

I want to change value element in products file according to rule file. Example, If for 3D name element, value  element is yes in products file then according to rules file the value element of that will be 3D capable in products file. So it will be

```
<Attr>
  <name>3D</name>
  <value>3D Capable</value>
</Attr>
```

So I thought of using Linq to pick data from both xml if name element matches in both and I do not want two foreach loops but since the data in Rules.xml is not uniform, I am stuck.

Comment: could you show us the steps you tried with LINQ and why that did not work?

Comment: Actually I am very new to Linq so I am not able to write query for non uniform xml(Rules.xml).

Comment: How should proper `transformingvalue` should be taken for *Battery Life*? And btw. both xml are not correct XML Documents (no root element) unless you're not showing everything.

Comment: for Battery Life, if 'value' from Product.xml is less than 60 which is the 'comparingvalue' in Rules.xml then hours which is the first 'transformingvalue' will be picked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about one foreach loop to iterate over two `IEnumerable<XElement>`?

```
var fileA = productA.Descendants("Attr").Select(a => new
{
    Name = a.Element("name").Value,
    Value = a.Element("value").Value
});
var fileB = productB.Descendants("Attr").Select(a => new
{
    Name = a.Element("name").Value,
    Value = a.Element("value").Value
});
var rules = xe.Descendants("Attr").Select(r => new
{
    Names = r.Elements("name"),
    Category = r.Element("category").Value
    TransformingValue = r.Elements("transformingvalue")
    ComparingValue = r.Element("comparingvalue").Value
});
foreach(var node in fileA) {
    // Or whatever comparison your need from Rules.xml
    if (fileB.Any(n => n.Name == node.Name && n.Value != node.Value))
    {
         //DoSomething();
         //break;?
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that the nodes have different number of elements in Rules.xml. So according to my understanding the fileB only will store name and value but I want all the elements of nodes because I want to change the value according to transformingValues in my Rules.xml and the transformingValue elements are not same in number across Attr nodes.

Comment: Where I've written `whatever comparison your need from Rules.xml` you are going to have to implement your own logic for pulling the necessary fields from Rules.xml

Comment: pardon me for asking this stupid question, if productB has more elements than just name and value then can it be accessed by fileB?
Like if productB has category node also then will fileB.Element("category") work?

Comment: Sure, just add all required fields into the `.Select`. If they don't exist, you can just set them to `null`

Comment: yes actually at this point only I am stuck because if you notice in Rules.xml file the occurrence of 'transformingvalue' is only once in 1st Attr but in 3rd Attr its 3 times. So in .Select how should I write?

Comment: Added sample of rules

Comment: so in this if I want to access `tranformingvalue` id="3" then will I be able to access through `TransformingValue`?

Comment: Yup, `Elements` returns an `IEnumerable` list

Comment: Awesome... You really saved me from struggling for this.